# Java CQL Driver Invalid Query Exception when querying Timestamp

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I am attempting to query Cassandra with a timespan based query, and I am hitting an InvalidQueryException when running the query from my Java service.

Let's say I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id uuid,
  ts timestamp,
  data text,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, ts)
)
```

Using `cqlsh` I am able to query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83db3a AND Time >= '2016-09-26T16:39:15+0000';
```

In my Java service, the following code throws an `InvalidQueryException`

```
    Statement select = QueryBuilder.select().all()
                    .from(keyspace, tableName)
                    .where(eq("user_id", userUUID))
                    .and(gte("ts", startTime));

    session.execute(select);
```

The error thrown is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (24)] with root cause
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (24)
```

If I try to execute the query as a `String` rather than a `Statement`, it works fine. Here is an example.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83db3a AND ts >= '2016-09-26T16:39:15+0000';";
```

A couple of questions:

1. Why am I getting an exception saying "Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date"? The [CQL documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) says we can input the timestamp as an `integer` or `String`.
2. What do I need to do to get my query working using the `Statement` class? My service receives the timestamp in the `Date ISO 8601` format.

Comment: Hello, did you find how to fix this? I encountered this same problem recently which is very frustrating. Same query runs in cqlsh but wont run from program. If i copy the query form debug log and paste in cqlsh, it runs fine...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by converting it to a string before I execute.

```
 Results = cassandraSession.execute(cqlStatement.toString());
```

Only way I could get it to work with timestamps.

This will work if you only need to use the date in the where clause...

[Select in Cassandra with Java (datastax driver) by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334912/select-in-cassandra-with-java-datastax-driver-by-timestamp)